# Simple AR Overlay on Mobile Device Camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm new to AR. But I have a general idea of what I want to do.

I want to overlay UI elements in Android on top of the camera input.

These UI elements will be updated in real time, according to gyroscope, gps inputs, via bluetooth, wifi, etc.

Something like Yelp's AR app, but the UI element values are updated much more frequently.

Do I need Vuforia or Unity for something like this? Or Android will be good enough?

What would be the fastest way?

What would be the recommended way?

Thanks.

Comment: I use Unity Vuforia and I've not been able to find an answer. Hoping this question gets one.

Comment: @AugmentedJacob Is Unity Vuforia good for overlay quick-changing UI elements? Wondering if Unity is overkill for this purpose.

Comment: No, its not overkill. As a matter of fact, it's easier to use Unity than the SDK, simply because if you want to turn or move something, you just have to do so with a click of a button than code it out. But that's just my opinion. And wrt the question, I've got an idea, let me test it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, my idea worked. This applies for Vuforia Unity. If you want an onscreen object/button, follow this.

All you need to do is make your ARCamera a parents of your desired object. And then voila, it starts to work. Wherever you point your camera, the object is there.

For Vuforia SDK, I'm not entirely sure how the camera works, but if you can link the camera's position to the button/objects position. Or maybe if the camera is a class, then you could make the button an class object.

Check it out and let me know how it fairs for SDK.

If all fails, switch to Unity ;) jk.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link for SDK Comparsion:
http://bit.ly/ARSDKs

And this a sample for "Marker based Tracking" Using Unity3D & Metaio SDK
http://bit.ly/ARTrkingSample